# How to add new sheets to existing excel workbook using apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to write List data into multiple excel sheet in one work book. like for first list, the code will create new workbook and create new sheet for list[1], for second list it will create new sheet in existing workbook and so on. so i wrote below code. but it doesnt work and i am able to see only first sheet for list[1]. can someone help me to provide any alternate resolutions?

the below code i have written

```
    ArrayList<List<String>> tempresultdata=this.getSummaryList();
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    String fileName="Path\\To\\XLS";
    File file = new File(fileName);
    FileOutputStream out;           
    if(!file.exists()) // This will create new workbook with new sheet if it doesnt exists{

                HSSFSheet mySheet = workbook.createSheet(sheetname);
                writeExcel(mySheet,tempresultdata);
    } else // This add new sheet to above created workbook {
            try {
                HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = (HSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(file);
                workbook=myWorkBook;
                HSSFSheet mySheet = (HSSFSheet) workbook.createSheet(sheetname);
                writeExcel(mySheet,tempresultdata);                 
            } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }   
    try{
        out = new FileOutputStream(fileName,true);
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        }catch(Exception e){ 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thanks,
Priyank Shah

Comment: Where is the code for `writeExcel`?

Comment: it is user defined fuctions. that mapped content of list to excel cells.

Comment: You're only ever adding one sheet, so surely having only one sheet in the output is to be expected?

Comment: @PriyankShah I am facing the same problem for creating multiple sheets in existing excel, can you keep the working application for exporting data to excel in multiple using servlets.

Answer (score 13):

If file does not exist then this code creates new file and also creates sample sheet1 but if file exists then it adds new sheet to existing excel file.

```
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
    File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "Sample.xls");
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

    if (file.exists()) {
        try {
            workbook = (HSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(file);
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet2");
    }
    else{
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet1");
    }
    workbook.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are only writing out the `sheet` not the `workbook`

Comment: yes, I am writing new sheet, i want to add that sheet to workbook.

Comment: My point is that you are passing `sheet` to `writeExcel` so I am assuming it is only writing out the sheet not the book.

Comment: Hi John, But at the end this code will write entire sheet to that work book.
       try{
        out = new FileOutputStream(fileName,true);
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        }catch(Exception e){ 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: I see that you have a `List<List<String>>` and you are trying to create a new sheet for each outter list. However, I do not see where you looping through the outter list creating a new sheet per list. Seems that you only create one sheet even if there are 8 lists.

Answer (score 2):

While working with existing workbook , You should not create a file object , Just need to Provide the File Location to `FileInputStream` object and pass it's reference to workbook object, then do whatever you want to do with the existing file. To add a sheet just use create Method command

```
public void AddsheetintoExistingworkbook(String sheetname) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException{

    //***************************Add a sheet into Existing workbook***********************************************


 String path="C:\\Workspace\\Selenium_2.53\\src\\InputFiles\\Temp.xlsx";
 fileinp = new FileInputStream(path);
 workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileinp);
 workbook.createSheet(sheetname);

 fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
    workbook.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
 System.out.println("File is written successfully");    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bhaskar's code to work things out and to use WorkbookFactory you will probably need to donwload poi-ooxml-3.7.jar file.

Here is the link for you:

http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/3.7

Answer (score 1):

To add more than one Excel sheet to a new Excel file, those sheets need to be created from one workbook, and written once to the file output stream

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

public class JustATest {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {       

        XSSFWorkbook AWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); //Create blank workbook 

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            XSSFSheet spreadsheet = AWorkbook.createSheet(" Employee "+i);

            // the follwing code is to create dummy data in sheets 
            // is similar to the one at tutorialPoint.com
            XSSFRow row;            
            //This data needs to be written (Object[])
            Map < String, Object[] > empinfo =    new TreeMap< String, Object[] >();
            empinfo.put( "1", new Object[] { "EMP ID", "EMP NAME", "DESIGNATION" });
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                empinfo.put( j+2+"", new Object[] {  j+2+"", "Fadel K", "Technical Manager" });                
            }          
            //Iterate over data and write to sheet
            Set<String> keyid = empinfo.keySet();
            int rowid = 0;
            for (String key : keyid){
               row = spreadsheet.createRow(rowid++);
               Object [] objectArr = empinfo.get(key);
               int cellid = 0;
               for (Object obj : objectArr){
                  Cell cell = row.createCell(cellid++);
                  cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
               }
            }            
            // dummy data creation over.
        }       

        // here you write all sheets at once, by writing the entier workbook
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("AllData.xlsx"));
        AWorkbook.write(out);
        out.close();               
   }
}
```